# how to apply indices on ROW in sectioned UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a sectioned UITableview.Some thing like this :
[image]

significant code is :

```
animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo",@"TIGER"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo",@"Tarantula"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey",@"Tasmanian Devil"],
            };

animalSectionTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"C",@"D", nil];
animalIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];
```

relevant delegate:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return animalIndexTitles;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
return [animalSectionTitles indexOfObject:title];
}
```

Now the requirement is that, if i press "T" from the indices, table  should show all results with "T", along with their sect5ion, for example section B and C both have words (tiger and Tarantula).If i press "T" from the indices, table should show me section "B" with row tiger and section "C" with row Tarantula.

How can i  acheive this.I am thinking to remove all indices stuff and simply use search bar with search functionality.

Comment: Why do you have "TIGER" under "B" and "Tarantula" under "C"?

Comment: i have added tiger and Tarantula to demonstrate my problem

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense. You wouldn't scatter your "T" values throughout different sections. They would all be under the "T" section. The whole idea is to properly alphabetize the values under the proper section. Then when the user taps one of the letters down the right side, that section is scrolled into view. It's not meant to act as a filter that shows improperly scattered values.